# Массив string в MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

У меня есть бд MySql для пользователей, мне нужно к ним сделать список ссылок, у каждого юзера он свой. У меня также есть класс `Account`, и в нём `Links`; Так вот

```
Links[] l = new Links[6];
```

Нужно запихнуть в MySql в одно поле `links` в строке с логином, чтобы они и там были, и в программе расшифровывались нормально.

Желательно без лишних файлов в папке с программой.

Comment: Для этого нужно делать отдельную таблицу, а не запихивать в 1 поле и потом расшифровывать

Comment: @Zergatul Получается под 15000 юзеров делать 15000 таблиц?

Comment: Таблица - одна. И в каждой записи - ID юзера и одна из его ссылок.

Comment: @Akina У каждого юзера своё кол-во ссылок, у одного максимум 10, у другого 50... Число всегда варьируется, как друзья в Steam. Нужно список наподобие друзей в Steam.

Comment: @Osid почитайте основы баз данных, что такое внешний ключ

Comment: Можно засунуть эти линки в json или xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите хранить одним полем в базе, то можете записывать ссылки в базу через ";" или "\n", а потом в основной программе сделать так

```
string linksInDb = "взять; из; базы;";
List<string> links = linksInDb.Split(';').ToListArray();
```

Но правильным вариантом будет хранить в базе в отдельной таблице так:

```
UserId     Link
id         ссылка  
id         ссылка
...        ...
```

ссылки можно хранить тоже в отдельной таблице, и подставлять только айдишник, что позволит не писать ссылки по нескольку раз, а просто использовать Id нужной ссылки.